two-way monoidal orbit
Let $M$ be a monoid acting on a set $X$. We can define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $x \sim y$ iff $y \in M x$ and $x \in M y$. Given an element $x \in X$ we can let $R_x \subseteq X$ be the elements equivalent to $x$. Is there a standard name for $R_x$? I am inclined to call it the "two-way orbit" of $x$.

In the case $M=\mathbb{N}$, this is commonly called the "grand orbit" of $x$ (in the context of dynamical systems, where you think of the action of $M$ as iterating some function on $X$).  I don't recall having seen that term used for more general monoids, but it would be very natural to generalize it to them.
